# trying to make IE trigger change on Enter key in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

in Chrome and FF when hitting enter in textbox will trigger change, not in IE, so I'm trying to make it do the same

this is what I have for the moment:
http://jsfiddle.net/nV4SA/8/

```
//fix for IE to trigger change on enter
    $("input[type=text]")
        .on("change", function(e) {
            $.data(this, "value", this.value);
        }).on("keyup", function(e) {
            if (e.which === 13 && this.value != $.data(this, "value")) {
                $(this).change();
            }
        });
```

the only drawback with this code is that in IE users hits enter the change happens, but the change will happen again when textbox loses focus

Answer (score 2):

Instead of triggering `change` it seems to work if you trigger `blur` in IE only. Use `$.support` to test for IE.

```
/* false in IE.. see jQuery APU */
var changeBubble=$.support.changeBubbles;

$("input[type=text]").on("change", function(e) {
    $.data(this, "value", this.value);
}).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && this.value != $.data(this, "value") && !changeBubble) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    }
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nV4SA/10/

`$.support` API docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

EDIT: Note that `$.support.changeBubbles` is true in IE9 but not IE <9. Solution may not be bulletproof. Although frowned upon you may need to use browser sniffing or try finding other support properties in `$.support` that work in all versions of IE only

Comment: this solution will make the textbox loose focus ( also I had to remove the changeBubbles to make it work on IE9)

Comment: might be fighting an uphill battle. Why the need to trigger change with enter key? Understanding the UI might help better

Comment: `$.support` is no longer supported(*irony*) by jQuery. But for me it works without the check for IE too -> always blur on enter.